# How do I add non-NuGet packages to ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

This is possibly the dumbest question ever, but I've downloaded the jsPDF library from here: [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf). It's not offered through the NuGet packages, so how do I then use it in my .NET MVC project solution? Do I need to move the downloaded folder to the "Packages" folder in my project's directory? Do something else?

Obviously, I'm a total newbie to this, so please keep your answers uncomplicated if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Nuget package is literally just a zip file of a compiled project. If it's C# code, it's a collection of DLLs, but depending on the project, it could have static resources like CSS, JS, etc. It could also have views or other resources. The long and short, is that all of this is just pretty much dumped into your project when you include a Nuget package, much as if you had simply added it yourself.

The slight exception is with DLLs, which are placed in `packages` simply to keep them organized, and then simply referenced by the project they were added to. Therefore, in order to add something not available as a Nuget, you simply just add all the stuff to your project. If there's JS/CSS and such, then just drop that somewhere in your project. If there's DLLs, create some place to house those on your filesystem, and then add a reference to them in your project. I would *not* recommend sticking them in the `packages` directory, because that's managed by Nuget, and it could clobber your DLLs if you put them there.